# Java runtime message's error

Tags: java, output, runtime-error, runtime

I have a problem with the "output" of the program. Could you tell me if it's possible to discover the bug in the program?

```
/**
 * @(#)Java_test.java
 *
 * Java_test application
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 1.00 2018/8/8
 */

public class Java_test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO, add your application code
        int a = 5;
        a = a + 1;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

---

```
----Configuration: Java_test - JDK version -10.0.2 <Default> - <Default>--------------------(Build Output)
javac: invalid flag: C:\Users\estel\OneDrive\Documents\JCreator LE\MyProjects\Java_test\src\Java_test.java 
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options

Process completed.
```

Comment: What's the full command you're using to compile?

Comment: I don't think there's a bug in your program, just an invalid javac flag.  Is the path `LE\MyProjects\Java_test\src\Java_test.java` correct?

Comment: It seems you forgot to put quotes around your path, which contains a space character (and must thus be quoted). But that's just a guess since you didn't post the command.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, compilation is failing because you have a space in your file path and you need to wrap it in quotes like so:
`javac "C:\Users\estel\OneDrive\Documents\JCreator LE\MyProjects\Java_test\src\Java_test.java"`